# node.js most performant way to skip a part of code

Tags: node.js, optimization

In compiling languages like C we have a preprocessor that can be used to skip parts of program without compiling them, effectively just excluding them from the source code:

```
#ifdef SHOULD_RUN_THIS
    /* this code not always runs */
#endif
```

So that if `SHOULD_RUN_THIS` is not defined, then the code will never be run.

In node.js we don't have a direct equivalent of this, so the first thing I can imagine is

```
if (config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS) {
    /* this code not always runs */
}
```

However in node there is no way to guarantee that `config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS` will never change, so `if (...)` check will be performed each time in vain.

What would be the most performant way to rewrite it? I can think of

a) create a separate function to allow v8-optimizations:

```
function f(args) {
    if (config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS) {
        /* this code not always runs */
    }
}
// ...
f(args);
```

b) create a variable to store the function and set it to an empty function when not needed:

```
var f;
if (config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS) {
    f = (args) => {
        /* this code not always runs */
    }
}
else {
    f = function () {} // does nothing
}
// ...
f(args);
```

c) do not create a separate function, just leave it in place:

```
if (config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS) {
    /* this code not always runs */
}
```

What is the most performant way? Maybe some other way...

Answer (score 1):

i personally would adopt ...

```
if (config.SHOULD_RUN_THIS) {
    require('/path/for/conditional/module');
}
```

the module code is only required where needed, otherwise it is not even loaded in memory let alone executed.

the only downside is that it is not readily clear which modules are being required since your require statements are not all positioned at the top of the file.

es6 modularity adopts this dynamic module request approach.

PS use of config like this is great since, you can for example, use an environment variable to determine your code path. Great when spinning up, for example, a bunch of docker containers that you want to behave differently depending on the env vars passed to the docker run statements.

apologies for this insight if you are not a docker fan :) apologies i am waffling now!

Comment: This is a good idea and though I don't use docker containers, using env variables is indeed very handy.

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for a preprocessor for your Javascript, why not use [a preprocessor for your Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocessor)?  It's node-compatible and appears to do what you need.  You could also look into writing a plugin for Babel or some other JS mangling tool (or v8 itself!)

If you're looking for a way to do this inside the language itself, I'd avoid any optimizations which target a single engine like v8 unless you're sure that's the only place your code will ever run.  Otherwise, as has been mentioned, try breaking out conditional code into a separate module so it's only loaded if necessary for it to run.

Comment: This is very intersting module, I'll take a look how it works